# How to copy attribute of a Node while injecting a Blank Node

Tags: xslt

**I have a XML as**

```
<ParentA Id="P1" Title="Parent1 Details>   
    <Child Att1="abcd" Id="Id1" Title="Public" Bind="Prop1" AccessItem="0">
    </Child>
</Parent>
<ParentA Id="P2" Title="Parent2 Details>   
    <Child Att1="abcde" Id="Id2" Title="Public" Bind="Prop2" AccessItem="0">
    </Child>    
 </Parent>
```

**I want to Inject a Blank Tag ParentB as shown below ParentA.**

```
<ParentA Id="P1" Title="Parent1 Details>
    <ParentB>
        <Child Att1="abcd" Id="Id1" Title="Public" Bind="Prop1" AccessItem="0">
        </Child>
    </ParentB>
</Parent>
```

**When i add below XSL code, the attributes of ParentA are moved over to ParentB.**

```
<xsl:template match="ParentA">              
<xsl:copy>   
    <ParentB>                     
        <xsl:apply-templates/>    
    </ParentB>  
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**I get the following output. No attributes on ParentA or ParentB.**

```
<ParentA>
    <ParentB>
        <Child Att1="abcd" Id="Id1" Title="Public" Bind="Prop1" AccessItem="0">
        </Child>
    </ParentB>
</Parent>
```

**When i add below code.**

```
<xsl:template match="ParentA">              
<xsl:copy>   
    <ParentB>                     
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />  
    </ParentB>  
</xsl:copy>
```

**I get the following output with attributes of ParentA being copied over to ParentB**

```
<ParentA>
<ParentB Id="P1" Title="Parent1 Details">
    <Child Att1="abcd" Id="Id1" Title="Public" Bind="Prop1" AccessItem="0">
    </Child>
</ParentB>
```

**Expecting for some help**

Comment: Your XML input is invalid!!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ParentA">              
    <xsl:copy>   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> 
        <ParentB>                     
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />  
        </ParentB>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```